# Is there any relation between manifold of $SO(3)$ and Riemannian manifold? And what is the negative definite metric in Lie algebra mean?

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Well, Riemannian manifolds possess the positive definite inner product, so this positive definite inner product induces a positive definite metric tensor, right?

My professor told us, the Cartan Killing metric of Lie algebra $SO(3)$ is negative definite, what's this mean?
Does this mean the manifold of $SO(3)$ is not a Riemannian manifold?

I am now really confused.

Comment: $SO(3)$ admits a bi-invariant metric and hence is a homogeneous Riemannian manifold. The Killing form on the Lie algebra is negative definite, which says that it is compact semisimple - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829205/if-g-is-a-compact-semisimple-lie-group-then-its-killing-form-is-negative-defini).

Comment: Thank you so much！by the way，are "canonical metric" and "Cartan Killing metric" the same thing？

Comment: @FishinDiracSea Not always. The Cartan-Killing form $\kappa$ induces a symmetric bilinear form on $TG$, but it may not be a Riemannian (or even Pseudo-Riemannian) metric. In the compact semisimple case, $\kappa$ is negative definite, so it's customary (but not required) to use $-\kappa$ as a metric.